# Paperclip image reprocess, images broken and lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have production data missing.

I changed styling for my images, based on the model in which images were uploaded to optimize the site. I am using paperclip and s3 for storing. This is the code I used.

```
has_attached_file :attachment, styles: lambda {|attachment| {
  original: (

    attachment.instance.source_type.eql?("Trip")? ["1200x800>", 'jpg'] :
    attachment.instance.source_type.eql?("User")? ["200x200>", 'jpg'] : 
    attachment.instance.source_type.eql?("Milestone")? ["700x500>", 'jpg'] :
    attachment.instance.source_type.eql?("Moment")? ["700x500>", 'jpg'] :["10x10>", 'jpg']
  ),
  medium: (
    attachment.instance.source_type.eql?("Trip")? ["500x300>", 'jpg'] : ["10x10", 'jpg']
  )
}
}
```

This is the command I used for reprocessing.

```
Image.find_each { |image| image.attachment.reprocess!}
```

This worked fine on the testing server. So, I used this on production data. Now ,some of the images are missing from production and for some its showing access denied. Below are the couple of image URL you can check to see what exactly is happening:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/roadmojoproductionbucket/images/attachments/000/000/163/medium/IMG_132801219374746.jpg?1417959351
http://s3.amazonaws.com/roadmojoproductionbucket/images/attachments/000/000/164/original/IMG_133237947098173.jpg?1417959352

What do I do get back these images back?